# PDO:: How I get value from print_r

Tags: arrays, pdo

I have this code...

```
$sth = $connection->prepare("SELECT jmeno FROM users WHERE username = 'admin'");
$sth->execute();
$info = $sth->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
print_r ($info);
```

and I am getting this

```
Array ( [0] => tomas )
```

if I use echo['name'] = Undefined index: name,

How Can I get only "tomas" please??

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $info[0];
```

Enjoy your code!

Answer (score 0):

[PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) returns an array, that is why you have got that strange result. After you know this, you can search yourself how to print array's elements from PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php).

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `fetch` instead of `fetchAll`. And also use `FETCH_ASSOC` as the fetch style:

```
$sth->execute();
$info = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$jmeno = $info['jmeno'];
```